# Need assistance with a few Validation errors

Tags: html, css, validation

Hey i'm running my index page through the W3C validator and am getting 6 errors and need some help. The errors are:-

```
Line 57, Column5: error parsing attribute name
Line 57, Column 5: attributes construct error
Line 57, Column 5: Couldn't find end of Start Tag div line 56
Line 67, Column 14: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 14 and div 
Line 69, Column 11: Opening and ending tag mismatch: html line 4 and body 
Line 70: Extra content at the end of the document
```

This is my code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/10000658.css" title="default" />
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/default.css" title="assignment2" />

    <title>The Garden Co. | Home </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
           <h1>The Garden Co.</h1>
        </div>

             <div id="menu">

                    <h1>Contents</h1>

                    <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="plants_section/index.html">Catalogue</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="plants_section/plant1.html">Plant 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="plants_section/plant2.html">Plant 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="plants_section/plant3.html">Plant 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a class="section" href="plants_section/index3.html">Report</a>

                        </li>

            <li>
                            <a class="section" href="plants_section/index4.html">Report(2)</a>

                        </li>


                        <li><a class="section" href="plants_section/form.html">Contact</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div><!-- end menu -->

              <div id="content">
                 <div id="contentWrapper">
                    <h1>Welcome</h1>

                    <div class="text"
                    ***<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed eros quis leo sollicitudin tempus.  </p>***

                </div>
            ***</div><!-- end contentWrapper -->***
             </div><!-- end content -->

           <div id="footer">
              <p>&copy; My name, 2012.</p>
           </div>

        </div><!-- end wrapper  -->

***</body>***
***</html>***
```

If anyone can help solve these errors, it would be greatly appreciated. EDIT: Bolded lines are where the errors are found

Comment: it would help if you highlighted or marked the rows somehow that are corresponding to the errors.

Comment: The error messages are very clear what you did wrong. Why don't you try yourself to look for the solutions?

Comment: I've used bold (***) on all the lines containing errors, + @JohannesKlauß I have tried for quite a while before resorting to asking others for help

Answer (score 4):

You didn't close a `<div>` tag on line 57:

```
<div class="text"
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that your DIV tag isn't closed on line 57:

Should be:
`<div class="text">`

Answer (score 1):

looks like this is the cause of most of your problems:

```
<div class="text"
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed eros quis leo sollicitudin tempus.  </p>
```

should probably be:

```
<div class="text">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed eros quis leo sollicitudin tempus.  </p>
</div><!--this is already there, just the tabbing is off so it looked like it was missing-->
```

fix that, and re-run it. let us know what errors are left.

Answer (score 1):

Start with fixing your  tag here:

```
<div class="text"
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed eros quis leo sollicitudin tempus.  </p>
```

Need to close the tag so it should read: (missing the ">")

```
<div class="text">
```

Rerun it then and let us know results.